# Runtime element substition in a tree structure

Tags: c++, rest, oop, design-patterns

I'm implementing a REST API client in c++ that needs to be able to discover the structure of the API at runtime. The structure of the REST API could change during the program execution as well. The API model is based on json arrays and objects. If an array is returned it means the retrieved element is a node and if an object is returned it means the retrieved element is a leaf.

In order to represent the data I'm modeling I decided to use the composite pattern to give a common interface to users to the tree structure (node or leaf).

And to provide hooks to my model to some GUI or CLI I decided to use the Visitor pattern in order to visit the nodes and leaves.

I tried to implement the discovery part of the model using the Visitor pattern as well but it is clearly not suited for the task because I need to replace previously allocated objects of a derived type to another type (eg: a leaf becomes a node). Which seems to me impossible using the Visitor pattern because an object can't replace itself.

I tried to add some container classes to wrap my objects but I ended up in a similar situation where I need an object to replace itself.

I read online about design patterns to try and find one that could help me out but I haven't found any that seems suitable.

Here's the code I have so far - the most relevant part is at the end (class Discover):

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

class Visitor;

class Element{
public:
  Element(std::string name, Element* parent) : name{ name }, parent{ parent }{}
  std::string get_name(){
    return name;
  }
  std::string get_url(){
    std::stack<std::string> url_stack;
    Element* ancestor = parent;
    url_stack.push(name);
    while(ancestor != NULL){
      url_stack.push(ancestor->name);
      ancestor = ancestor->parent;
    }
    std::string url;
    while(!url_stack.empty()){
      url.append(url_stack.top());
      url_stack.pop();
    }
    return url;
  }
  Element* get_parent(void){
    return parent;
  }
  virtual ~Element(void){};
  virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor) = 0;
private:
  std::string name;
  Element* parent;
};

class ElementEmpty : public Element{
public:
  ElementEmpty(std::string name, Element* parent = NULL) : Element(name, parent){}
  virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor);
};

class ElementLeaf : public Element{
public:
  ElementLeaf(std::string name, std::string value, Element* parent = NULL) : Element(name, parent), value{ value }{}
  virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor);
  std::string value;
};

class ElementComposite : public Element{
public:
  ElementComposite(std::string name, std::deque<std::string> value_names, Element* parent = NULL) : Element(name, parent){
    for(auto& vn : value_names){
      values.emplace_back(new ElementEmpty(vn, this));
    }
  }
  ~ElementComposite(){
    while(!values.empty()){
      delete values.back();
      values.pop_back();
    }
  }
  virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor);
  std::deque<Element*> values;
};

class Visitor{
public:
  virtual void visit(ElementEmpty& empty) = 0;
  virtual void visit(ElementLeaf& leaf) = 0;
  virtual void visit(ElementComposite& composite) = 0;
};


void ElementEmpty::accept(Visitor& visitor){
  visitor.visit(*this);
}

void ElementLeaf::accept(Visitor& visitor){
  visitor.visit(*this);
}

void ElementComposite::accept(Visitor& visitor){
  visitor.visit(*this);
}

class Printer : public Visitor{
public:
  virtual void visit(ElementEmpty& empty){
    std::cout << empty.get_name() << " is empty" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void visit(ElementLeaf& leaf){
    std::cout << leaf.get_name() << " is a leaf with value" << leaf.value << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void visit(ElementComposite& composite){
    std::cout << composite.get_name() << " is composite, visiting childrens" << std::endl;
    for(auto& v : composite.values){
      v->accept(*this);
    }
  }
};

class Discover : public Visitor{
public:
  virtual void visit(ElementEmpty& empty){
    discover(&empty);
  }
  virtual void visit(ElementLeaf& leaf){
    discover(&leaf);
  }
  virtual void visit(ElementComposite& composite){
    discover(&composite);
    for(auto& v : composite.values){
      v->accept(*this);
    }
  }
private:
  void discover(Element* element){
    std::string url = element->get_url();
    //HTTP GET (pseudo-code here to avoid adding irelevant code)
    json_val value = http_get(url);
    Element* new_element;
    if(value.is_array()){
      new_element = new ElementComposite(element->get_name(), value.as_array().as_deque(), element->get_parent());
    }
    else if(value.is_object()){
      new_element = new ElementLeaf(element->get_name(), value.as_string(), element->get_parent());
    }
    else{
      new_element = new ElementEmpty(element->get_name(), element->get_parent());
    }

    //TODO: How to set element to new_element? it's impossible since we are currently in element->accept()....
  }

};
```

Is there any way I could manage to replace previously allocated objects at runtime without having to add an array of pointers to the created objects and changing them when needed?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no easy means to "replace" existing objects in C++. C++ does not work this way. The only way this could be remotely possible is by manually invoking an existing object's destructor, then using placement `new`, and making sure that sufficient memory gets allocated in advance to hold the largest possible "replacement" object. If you don't know what that means, it probably means you wouldn't be able to correctly implement it according to all the rules of this, the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. The other option would be C++'s `std::variant`, perhaps.

Comment: Suggestion: produce a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that isolates your exact problem and ask a question about that. The code you have provided now is 1% substance, 99% noise. You will have a higher chance of someone understanding what your question even is if you just stick to the point.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The only way I could think of to replace the existing objects is precisely what you are describing. I'm a embedded c programmer and firmware designer so managing memory manually is not an issue for me. The thing is it seemed to me this was to much of a c way of doing things... I'll fallback to this solution if I can't find anything else. I'll have a look at std::variant to see if it could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the Elements you allocate in the provided code, you do so dynamically, by calling new.

Will that also be true for ALL elements that discover() might get called on?

If so, at the root of the call somewhere, will be the true owner of that Element. How about changing the interface of discover(), for example, so that it returns a pointer to the new Element, all the way down the call chain to the true owner of the old Element? Then that owner could just delete the old Element, and start storing the pointer to the freshly allocated Element in its place.

Of, course, the usual - don't use raw pointers, use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr, or whatever else is suitable, etc. But the above code transformation is still possible with those as well.

Comment: Hi! I've just tested this method following your recommandations by addind a ReturningVisitor interface with visit functions that returns a Element* and using this interface as a base for my derived class Discover. Also added the required accept methods to my element classes. It seems to work really well. I've only tested converting an ElementEmpty to a ElementLeaf because adding the necessary code for the ElementComposite is going to be a bit more challenging but it sure looks like it's going to work. I'll come back to let you know if it works well and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm having a few memleaks when replacing objects in the deque but I'll figure it out. Everything else seems to be working well! Thanks again!

Comment: Great! As mentioned before, if you start using std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr instead of raw pointers, it will become easier not to accidentally introduce memory leaks.

Comment: I'm looking into unique_ptr right now, it looks like it suits my needs. The only small change I had to do in my implementation is to have the discover() function only return the json object and not a Element* because I have to react differently according to the transformation, if any, is occuring (eg: EmptyElement to CompositeElement   vs   no changes at all   vs   etc...). Sooo close to testing it on a live API! :)